# Periodically CachingConnectionFactory creates each time new connection to check if queue is available

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have application which dynamically creates the new SMLC to listening to the given queues.
But when the given queue does not exist on the RabbitMQ I have observed strange behaviour, i.e CachingConnectionFactory periodically creates each time new connection to check if queue is avaliable. What cause that threads count increase periodically - in my application reached ~ 4k threads.
1) Is it expected behaviour?
2) Is it possible to change this behaviour?
**spring-amqp version 1.7.4.RELEASE**

Comment: Any chances to share with us some simple Spring Boot app to play from our side? Thanks